# Why xtext enum pollutes the keywords?

Tags: enums, keyword, dsl, xtext

Below is my grammar:

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"

Model:
    greetings+=Table*;

Table:
    'table' name=ID type=Type

;

enum Type: COLUMN | ROW;
```

The below string is not valid instance:

```
table ROW COLUMN
```

Is this a keywords pollution? `ROW` can act as the name of table. Why xtext does treat it as a Type? It has context to determine it.

Did I misunderstand something? How can I avoid this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

this is how xtext enums work. enum literals become a keyword.

you have basically 2 options

(1) get rid of the keywords shadowing ID rule

```
Table:
    'table' name=MyID type=Type

;

MyID: ID | "COLUMN" | "ROW";
```

may need adaption of proposalprovider for MyID

(2) handle enums differently. this works with a manually maintained metamodel only

```
MyEnum returns importedPackage::MyEnum : ID;
```

- adoptions to value converter and content assist to get proper errors on parsing and proper proposals when editing

Example

```
Model:
    greetings+=Greeting*;

Greeting:
    'Hello' name=ID value=MyEnumDataTypeRule;

//TO be save MyEnum wold be better declared in a separate metamodel
// for sake of easyness i work here with literals that seem to be unlikely to conflict
// to tell xtext there are literals A B and C
enum MyEnum:
    A="___________a"|
    B="___________b"|
    C="___________c"
;

MyEnumDataTypeRule returns MyEnum:
    ID
;
```

Value Converter

```
class MyDslValueConverters extends DefaultTerminalConverters {

    @Inject
    MyEnumValueConverter myEnumValueConverter

    @ValueConverter(rule = "MyEnumDataTypeRule")
    def IValueConverter<MyEnum> MyEnumDataTypeRule() {
        return myEnumValueConverter
    }

}

class MyEnumValueConverter implements IValueConverter<MyEnum> {

    override toString(MyEnum value) throws ValueConverterException {
        return value.getName();
    }

    override toValue(String string, INode node) throws ValueConverterException {
        try {
            return MyEnum.valueOf(string)
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new ValueConverterException("MyEnum does not allow literal " + string, node, e)
        }

    }

    def static void main(String[] args) {
        MyEnum.valueOf("xxxx")
    }

}
```

Binding

```
class MyDslRuntimeModule extends AbstractMyDslRuntimeModule {

    override bindIValueConverterService() {
        MyDslValueConverters
    }

}
```

Content Assist

```
class MyDslProposalProvider extends AbstractMyDslProposalProvider {

    override complete_MyEnumDataTypeRule(EObject model, RuleCall ruleCall, ContentAssistContext context, ICompletionProposalAcceptor acceptor) {
        MyEnum.values.forEach[
            acceptor.accept(createCompletionProposal(getName(),context))
        ]
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, can you give more details about the option 2. it would be much helper if there is a example. @Christian

Comment: added an example. i cheated about the external metamodel though